# Using a remote console in a Typescript app with for an Office Add-In

Tags: reactjs, typescript, console.log

I'm creating an add-in for Excel. I'm using the Typescript/React framework.

I want to be able to jsut use `console.log` however this has proven to be difficult, and so I'm resorting to using [console.re](https://console.re/).

This ultimately comes down to doing the following:

1. Include `<script src="//console.re/connector.js" data-channel="YOUR-CHANNEL-NAME" id="consolerescript"></script>` in your `head` tag
2. run `console.re.log("My Message")`

and then it should appear in the browser under your channel name (I used the correct channel name, that wasn't the issue).

However, no matter what I try I can't get it to stop complaining about `TS2339: Property 're' does not exist on type 'Console'.`

I'm not sure if I need to extend the type definition or what, and if so, how can this be done properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved quite easily by adding the following snippet to `global.d.ts`

```
interface Console {
    re: any;
}
```

Then, in your application you can use something like:

```
var con = console.re;

con.log("This should work!")
```